# Blender 2.8 Smoke Sim Bug

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, physics, smoke-simulation

Recently, I started using 2.8 for smoke simulation. Everything looks normal until I render it out. Though I can preview the smoke in the viewport(render mode), it does not appear in the final render(F12).
Then, I found out that I have to bake the smoke in order to render it out. I even saw some article in the forum stated it is "mandatory" to have your smoke baked.
But is it? I mean I'm not a expert in blender but I pretty sure that baking is not mandatory back in 2.79, right?
Is this some kind of bug or something, any suggestion?

(BTW, I'm using cycles in the 2.8)

THX

Answer (score -1):

You don’t need to bake.
Try adding a Volume Scatter node to Smoke Domain and connect it to Volume input of the material. Also delete the standart BSDF.